# quarkus access-logs do not show mdc content after clearing mdc in JAX-RS response filters

Tags: quarkus, mdc

I just want to clear MDC content when filter chain is completed. I realized after clearing MDC in LoggingFilter class, Quarkus access logs do not log the content I put in. What I expect is that it should be logged, then ContainerResponseFilter should be triggered. Somehow logging of quarkus access log happens after respose filter of JAX-RS

Do you have any idea how can I change the order?
I want to log MDC content in quarkus access log, then clear the MDC.

```
@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {
    java.util.logging.Logger logger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger(GreetingResource.class.getName());

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        logger.info("a log message");

        return "Hello RESTEasy";
    }
}
```

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.jboss.logging.MDC;

@Provider
public class LoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        MDC.put("test", "testValue");

    }

    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext, final ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
        MDC.clear();
    }
}
```

logs =>

- {"timestamp":"2023-11-24T16:06:08.422+03:00","sequence":1994,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.logmanager.Logger","loggerName":"org.acme.GreetingResource","level":"INFO","message":"a log message","threadName":"executor-thread-0","threadId":85,**"mdc":{"test":"testValue"}**,"ndc":"","hostName":"hj9xgjxrql","processName":"code-with-quarkus-dev.jar","processId":12056}
- {"timestamp":"2023-11-24T16:06:08.434+03:00","sequence":1995,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.logging.Logger",**"loggerName":"io.quarkus.http.access-log"**,"level":"INFO","message":"127.0.0.1 - - 24/Nov/2023:16:06:08 +0300 "GET /hello-resteasy HTTP/1.1" 200 14","threadName":"executor-thread-0","threadId":85,**"mdc":{}**,"ndc":"","hostName":"hj9xgjxrql","processName":"code-with-quarkus-dev.jar","processId":12056}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quarkus uses Jboss logging internally, so leaving clearing of MDC context to Quarkus solve my issue.

There is also one discussion related to clearing MDC in Quarkus. https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/27254

Final LoggingFilter class should be like below to have both java.util.logging(JUL) and quarkus.access.log to have MDC content.

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.jboss.logging.MDC;

@Provider
public class LoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        MDC.put("test", "testValue");

    }

}
```